# Informing new-users about the MWE

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Often (or mostly) we all encounter, when a new user asks a question that there is no `MWE` (done that myself). Also, we mostly ask them to post an `MWE` via comment.

So, apart from giving a tour of the site when they join, will it be a good idea to inform the users (only when they ask their first or first-few questions) about the `MWE`? For instance, a `marque` or a `highlight` on top of the page where the question is being typed.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7749/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7733/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7489/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7388/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6813/35864 and linked questions.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I will have a look into them.

Comment: Look at Section 3 here: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf

Comment: No. Don't do this. We discussed this enough times.

Comment: How's an MWE different from an MCVE?

Comment: @Mast From a first glance, I think MWE is just a SO variant of MCVE. However, I will dig deep into both to find whether if any difference exist.

Comment: Look also at section 3 here: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-3/tb123duck-format.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I've just been "migrated."  I think your question is very important.

["How to" on MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7883/170846)

The request for an MWE is so common that I can't help but wonder whether the submission process isn't aided by a "how to."  I expect there'd be more submissions and less need to request if the OP had some level of confidence regarding the mechanics of getting code into the question.